# Navigating to specific ContentFrame when refreshing NavigationView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I have an app which uses a `NavigationView` as a UI-control.

Now I have a `SettingsPage` where I can change the language of my UI between german and english.

I change the language with this code:

```
public static void German()
    {
        Log.Logger.Information("Language = German")

        ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "de-DE";
        DataCollection.Current.LanguageChangedEvent.LanguageChanged();
    }
```

The last line invokes an `EventHandler` which in turn invokes the following event on the `MainPage.xaml.cs` where the `NavigationView` is located.

```
public void ChangedLanguage(object source, EventHandlerBase e)
    {
        if (e.GetStatus())
        {

            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();

            Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());

            ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
        }
    }
```

As it's possible to see I just want to return the user to the `SettingsPage` after changing the language. 
But I always return back to the initial `HomePage` that I use when starting the app.

The code I use for the `NavigationView` is derived from the official [NavigationView sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) provided by Microsoft.

Is there any possible way to do this? The only possible thing I can imagine is to set a flag after the first page loading and then always check if that flag is set. But then I have the problem that I still could only land at the `SettingsPage` because I would have to make it the `else` destination for the flag-check.

Would really appreciate a more dynamic way if thats even possible :/

Greeting,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NavigationView sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) just is a simple code sample for your reference. You need to make some changes by your requirements.

> I just want to return the user to the SettingsPage after changing the language. But I always return back to the initial HomePage that I use when starting the app.

I've used the code on the document to make a code sample for testing. There're two places will cause your question.

First, in the `NavView_Loaded` event handler, it will always sets the home page as the selected item. But when you change the language, you re-navigate to 'MainPage' and make 'ContentFrame' navigate to 'SettingsPage'. At this time, the `On_Navigated` event handler will be first called. Then, the `NavView_Loaded` event handler will be called. That's the reason why your app always will return to home page.

Second, event if the NavigationView's SelectedItem has been set. But the NavigationView's [ItemInvoked event](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.ItemInvoked) will not be fired. So, what you see actually is not home page, it's a blank `Frame` control. You could use [SelectionChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.SelectionChanged) instead of ItemInvoked event. The SelectionChanged event will be fired when you set a new value for the NavigationView's SelectedItem. See the following sample:

```
private void NavView_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsSettingsSelected)
    {
        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
    }
    else
    {
        NavView_Navigate(args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem);
    }
}
```

Then, let's back to your original question:

> I can imagine is to set a flag after the first page loading and then always check if that flag is set. But then I have the problem that I still could only land at the SettingsPage because I would have to make it the else destination for the flag-check.

In my opinion, the flag will not affect you doing other things. You completely could define several flags. Please see my following code snippet for reference:

```
public static void German()
{
    Log.Logger.Information("Language = German")
    ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "de-DE";
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["IsSwitchingLanguage"] = true;
    DataCollection.Current.LanguageChangedEvent.LanguageChanged();
}
```

In your `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
public void ChangedLanguage(object source, EventHandlerBase e)
{
        if (e.GetStatus())
        {
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
            Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());

        }
}
```

In `NavView_Loaded` event handler, I made some changes:

```
private void NavView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        ...... 
        foreach (NavigationViewItemBase item in NavView.MenuItems)
        {
            var IsSwitchingLanguage = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["IsSwitchingLanguage"];
            if (IsSwitchingLanguage != null)
            {
                if ((bool)IsSwitchingLanguage)
                {
                    NavView.SelectedItem = NavView.SettingsItem as NavigationViewItem;
                    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["IsSwitchingLanguage"] = false;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (item is NavigationViewItem && item.Tag.ToString() == "home")
            {
                NavView.SelectedItem = item;
                break;
            }
        }

        ......
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explenation. I just implemented it and it works like a charm. :)